# backup MySQL database with QT

Tags: sql, mysql, qt

I have a GUI and user can select back up start and end date.

Is it possible with a sql query getting back up specific time distance.

Thank a lot

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  MySQL can get whatever you are storing in it.

That said I have no idea what you mean when you say:

> Is it possible with a sql query
>   getting back up specific time
>   distance.

so if you are storing "back up specific time distance" then you should be able to pull it up.  Please provide a clearer and more detailed question if you'd like a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question.

MySQL does not itself keep versions of the database. You can dump the current database, but that's it.

If you need the state at a particular time you'd need to design the database yourself and write a custom dump sql script.

You can do such a thing by never updating data, but always add a record with a (newer) timestamp. It's not all that easy (to design and to work with) and probably also not as fast, but it can be done.